# Full Page Cache not Working, no X-Magento-Cache-Debug header present

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish

The full-page cache is not working, when switching to developer mode, there is not even an `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` header

Comment: This can also be affected by load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, your Full Page cache is switched to "Built in cache", not varnish

For exmaple check the config value `system/full_page_cache/caching_application` and set it to "1" (2 would mean Varnish) -> so if you do not have Varnish installed, you will simply have no cache at all

```
bin/magento config:set --scope=default --scope-code=0 system/full_page_cache/caching_application 1
```